# CSS class naming - context in name or not?

Tags: html, css

I've got (hopefully) quite interesting questions, regarding code semantics. Should a class name be specific in it's role even in a bigger context? I'll just give an example:

I need a class for description container. But on the page, description exists in various places: `.page-slider, .offers, .articles` etc.

So there are 2 options: either name class `.description`, and style each one individually in contex of it's parent (for example `.page-slider .description`). Another way is to make it self-explainable, like `.offer-description`, `.slide-description` etc.

The pros of first option are short names and imposing keeping the code inherit depenend (the question is if it's stil the right way, SASS kinda encouraged me to limit the selectors inheritance)

The pros of self-explainable names could be their movability, better explained, if called directly throught jQuery, and minimizing the css nesting. The con is possibly long names in the future (bloat + additional parsing time for browser).

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Additional parsing time depends more on specificity than class length, I think. `.offers .description` will always lose to `.offers-description`, but unless you're making a site of quite some size, I don't think it will matter.

Answer (score 1):

The main factors to choose which method I would use would depend on answering these two questions:

**Do I understand what the selector selects?**

In your example ".slide-description" and ".page-slider .description" both explain what the selectors select. I personally am in favor of using ".page-slider .description" because it would say to me "I am a description of my parent item page-slider". Using ".slide-description" I would not understand that it is about a description of ".page-slider" without having to read the html (Maybe I would if you called it ".page-slider-description", but it still won't tell me it is a description of its parent-item).

**Will my selector allow me to make changes easily in the future?**

At some point you might decide to change some things on your website. Having to change every description will get boring fast. Instead you would be better off using ".description" to change some general styles of your ".description" divs. Since they all have the same function on the site they probably share a lot of properties. You can always override the ones you want using ".page-slider .description". Once again I seem to be in favor of the ".page-slider .description" -method.

Answer (score 0):

mmmm I would consider the visual design (if you have one) to see if the description class had common styles throughout its use in .slider, .offer and .articles If it did I would use .description and apply all the common styles. Then add additional styles based on the parent.

You could literally call your description container class .description-cont or .description-container.

If I was writing it in SASS I wouldnt make it self-explainable. I would simply have:

```
.slider{
   //styles
   .description{
   //styles
   }
}
```

Thanks

Comment: Thanks for the input. Speaking of SASS, the main problem i see with maintability, is that I'm using partials to modulize the styles. Using abstract .description class m8 bring troubles into finding the one, that is shared upon different parts. For example, general settings would have main description style, and slider and offers partial have it customized. Can't really move slider module around without knowing that description class exists in different place.